# What is the proper way to set up an MVC site in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-7

I'm new to MVC, and I have a Sandbox site I've set up to play around with.  I want to set the site up in local IIS(7) so that I don't have to debug every single time through VS.

The site (my Home Index) is located in D:\Projects\MVC\MVCLearn\MVCLearn\Views\Home

So, in IIS, the Application's Physical path is set to:
D:\Projects\MVC\MVCLearn\MVCLearn

When I run localhost/[appname], I get the "ASP.Net is a free web framework yada yada yada" welcome page.  What am I missing?  How can I see my app?  I've done copious amounts of Google searches, and I can't find one clear, concise, step-by-step walk through for setting up an MVC site in IIS7

Answer (score 0):

OOOHHHHHHHHHH, I get it!!!!!!!!

A raw URL call of the application (localhost/[appname]) defaults to the Index of the Home Controller.  That, by default, launches the Home/Index.cshtml page, which IS pretty much the Welcome to ASP.Net page I was seeing!  It was working correctly all along!  I was getting confused... I thought that page was a landing page built into IIS or something, but that WAS my Index page!  It was put there when Visual Studio built my project!  The reason Debug was showing me something different was because that was taking me directly to a different controller with a different view that I was working on!